# natbib package error

Tags: errors, natbib

I have been using the regular \cite command for my citations all the time. But now I used the 'natbib' package and instead used \citep and \citet, but this keeps giving me errors in the natbib.sty file which it creates. I also get the error 'command \bibhang already defined'.

Does anyone have experience with this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}
\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]

\chapter*{Declaration}

\chapter*{Abstract}

 \chapter*{List  of abbrevations and symbols}

 \tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

as mentioned in \citet{england2002}

\section{Insurance industry}


\section{IBNR Claims and Claims Reserving}

\section{Link with GLM}


\section{Robustification and Problems}

\section{Applications}

\chapter{Body}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

using this .bib file:

```
@article{england2002,
title={Stochastic claims reserving in general insurance},
author={England, Peter D and Verrall, Richard J},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={8},
number={03},
pages={443--518},
year={2002},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}
```

Comment: Why, for gods sake, do you want to use old and dusty  `natbib` if you are already using the modern and full of features `biblatex`?

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{natbib}` and the `\bibliographystyle{..}` line, but add the option "natbib" to the biblatex call.

Answer (score 6):

There are several problems with your example code.

- You should start by immediately *removing* both arguments from the `document` environment. The instruction should read

  ```
  \begin{document}
  ```

  rather than `\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]`.  The `document` environment does *not* take arguments. Nothing good is going to come from supplying arguments, optional or otherwise, to the `document` environment.
- Don't load both the `biblatex` package and the `natbib` package. Select one or the other, *but not both*.
- Assuming you want to continue with `natbib` (@Johannes_B's learned opinion notwithsstanding...), you need to observe that the `ieeetr` bibliography style is *not* compatible with authoryear-style citation call-outs. You should therefore load the `natbib` package with the options `numbers` and `comma`, *not* `authoryear` and `comma`. Don't forget to delete the instruction `\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}` and to replace `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography{bib/literature}` -- note: *no filename extension*. By the way, with numeric-style citation call-outs in use, `\citet` will give you a warning message; use `\cite` instead.
- If you do need or want authoryear-style citation call-outs along with IEEE-style formatted bib entries, I suggest you switch to the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style. If you go this route, be sure to omit the `numbers` option when loading `natbib`.

  The output from your (somewhat condensed) working example then is as follows.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@article{england2002,
  title    = {Stochastic claims reserving in general insurance},
  author   = {England, Peter D and Verrall, Richard J},
  journal  = {British Actuarial Journal},
  volume   = {8},
  number   = {03},
  pages    = {443--518},
  year     = {2002},
  publisher= {Cambridge University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % just for this example
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\begin{document}

as mentioned in \citet{england2002}, \dots

\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you move the part with the optional arguments for the `document` environment higher? Though you are explaining later, the first part sounds like this is specail for `natbib` usage.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Done. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks. Feel free to post a biblatex-based answer with a IEEE-related formatting option. Readers of this posting may find it useful to have two separate solutions.